# C++ program design

Tags: c++, modular

How to effectively design a C++ modular program? How to learn?

Answer (score 5):

For a beginner, you may want to take the "brute force" process:
1.  Write a simple `main` function in one file.
2.  Add some functionality, compile then test.
3.  Refactor (use this keyword in Google).

Here are some guidelines for refactoring (not all of them may apply at the same time):

- Repetitive functionality should be
  separated into another function.
- Repetitive functions should be put
  into a separate source file and
  shared.
- Code and data structures that share a
  common theme should be placed into a
  single module.
- Classes that share common methods and
  functions should inherit from a base
  class containing those common methods
  and functions.
- Use libraries to contain classes and
  functions of a common theme.

An alternative is to design a program into functional blocks and data structures.  Repeat until the blocks and classes are simple enough for a non-programmer to understand.  Then start implementing.  Test Driven Development is a good process to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ton of books especially about that - http://www.aristeia.com/books.html

Answer (score 1):

About the only answers to that kind of question that can even hope to fit in an answer here would be advice on [books to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

Read this: [http://www.amazon.com/Large-Scale-Software-Design-John-Lakos/dp/0201633620](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620)

Comment: ...and look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860796/your-thoughts-on-large-scale-c-software-design