# Modular programming in C++

Tags: c++, modular

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ program design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964013/c-program-design)

I want to know how modular programs are written in C++ i.e. how they are analysed, designed etc. Also names of reference books will be helpful.

Comment: This question is extremely broad...

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at a link about OOP: [OOP Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)

You'll want to learn about classes as classes are what drives modularity and object-oriented programming.

As for books I always liked [C++ From The Ground Up](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072228970)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see ***"Code Complete"*** by *Steve McConnell*.

Although it isn't *"C++ specific"* and it doesn't cover some *"deep"* aspects of proper application design, it could be a good place to start from.